# Unclear about V8 Garbage Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around exactly what will be garbage collected in Node.js by V8 and why (or why not). I have an example below using the `async.js` library.

I would love some insight into how V8 treats each case below (numbered from 1 to 6 in the comments).

Thanks in advance.

```
"use strict";

var async = require('async');

module.exports = {

    foo: function foo(shirt, callback) {

        async.series([

            function(next) {

                var pants = 'clown',
                    outfit = shirt + pants;

                // 1. will shirt be garbage collected?

                next(null, outfit);

            },

            function(next) {

                var err = new Error('can\'t touch this.'),
                    pants = 'hammer',
                    outfit = shirt + pants;

                // 2. will shirt be garbage collected?

                setImmediate(function() {

                    // 3. will err be garbage collected?
                    // 4. will outfit be garbage collected?
                    // 5. will next be garbage collected?

                    next(err, outfit);

                })

            }

        ], function(err, results) {

            // 6. will callback be garbage collected?
            callback(err, results);

        });

    }


};
```

Comment: private variables get collected when they are no longer reachable, in your case when the callbacks fire and are no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `shirt` (1, 2) and `callback` (3) are referenced by inner functions. Thus their bindings have to be heap-allocated, and will only become garbage when all those inner functions have become garbage. In this example, that will happen after `async.series` has finished execution and dropped its reference to the array in which the inner functions are stored.

Of course, both `shirt` and `callback` are parameters. So even when `foo` drops all references to their values, its caller is likely to still have some, in which case these values will stay alive longer. You cannot know that locally.

Similarly, `err` (3) and `outfit` (4) will only become garbage when the inner function passed to `setImmediate`, which references them, becomes garbage (which will probably happen after it was executed), and when whatever continuation `next` passes them to does not keep them alive any longer. In this example, they are passed on to the `callback` parameter which you don't know anything about -- it could keep them alive indefinitely by storing them away somewhere, or just drop them immediately.

Finally, `next` (5) is an argument again. Its value will live at least until `setImmediate` fires. But it is a function that `async.series` creates, and to know how long it lives you'd also know in detail how `async.series` handles it (I assume it drops it immediately).

Comment: so according to the answer nothing leaks in here unless something outside is hanging onto the initial `shirt` and `callback` (assuming `async.series` is dropping all references). thanks!